# What would be the best way to compare a number with a range-number and know in what range did the number fit in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, range

What I want to do is be able to compare a number with a range of numbers, here I'm using a dictionary of arrays because is the only thing I can think of, but it could literately be anything.

In theory this is what I want is psudo code...

> myNumber
>
> rangeOne
>   rangeTwo
>   rangeThree
>
> Does myNumber fit in any of the range numbers? If yes in which one?

Here is what I have been playing with which kind of tells me whether it fits or not but it doesn't tell me in which range it did fit.

```
var myNumber = 72

let rangeNumbers = [
    "rangeOne": [72,104],
    "rangeTwo": [60,88],
    "rangeThree": [80,150],
]


for (rangeName, range) in rangeNumbers {

    for number in range {

        if myNumber <= number {
            print(number)
            print(rangeName)
            print("It's smaller/equal than \(myNumber)")
            print("-------------------------")
            break
        }else{
            print(number)
            print(rangeName)
            print("It's bigger than \(myNumber)")
            print("-------------------------")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to compare a number with a range-number and know in what range did the number fit?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather do something like that:

```
for (rangeName, range) in rangeNumbers {

    if range.count > 1
    {
        if myNumber >= range.first! && myNumber <= range.last! {
            print(rangeName)
        }
    }
}
```

That will work if your range array will contain only two elements min and max.

But better way would be use Range.

Answer (score 1):

use Range instead ..

```
let range: Range<Int> = Range(start: 1,end: 100)
range.contains(10) // true
```

... in your example

```
var myNumber = 72

let rangeNumbers = [
    "rangeOne": [72,104],
    "rangeTwo": [60,88],
    "rangeThree": [80,150],
]


let result = rangeNumbers.flatMap { (d) -> String? in
    let range: Range<Int> = Range(start: d.1[0],end: d.1[1] + 1)
    return range.contains(myNumber) ? d.0 : nil
    }
print(result)         // ["rangeOne", "rangeTwo"]

myNumber = 720

let result2 = rangeNumbers.flatMap { (d) -> String? in
    let range: Range<Int> = Range(start: d.1[0],end: d.1[1] + 1)
    return range.contains(myNumber) ? d.0 : nil
    }
print(result2)         // []
```

for safety, first check your dictionary ..

Comment: The only issue I see with this method, if I'm not mistaken is that I will have to have an array of ranges since I need to compare the number with multiple range of numbers. Thanks a lot, it's always good to know other possibility.

Comment: @fs_tigre no, you don't need to have an array of ranges. the best is to have Dictionary<String, Range<Int>>

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the clarification and the example.

Answer (score 1):

Time for some fun in swift, here is the one liner:

```
let rangeIndex = rangeNumbers.indexOf{ $0.1.first <= myNumber && $0.1.last >= myNumber }
```

Then you can use it like:

```
print(rangeNumbers[rangeIndex!])
```

Comment: Works! This is definitely a simplified version. Thanks a lot!

Comment: if the number in not in any of rages ... crash